# How to close the select certificate prompt programmatically using JS from UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, client-certificates

[Select Certificate promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzCvT.png)
How to close or avoid this prompt to select a certificate using JS.
Getting this select certificate popup on calling WhoAmI api.

Comment: I doubt it. This is outside of the realm that JS in a website context has access to.

Comment: @CBroe is there anything that we can do from UI to avoid this prompt?

Comment: Other than not connecting to a remote resource that apparently _demands_ this form of authentication, in the first place? Likely, no.